# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function

Tags: jquery, errors

I'm getting a strange jQuery error message in my theme. The message is showing in browser console-

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function

Note: I used the bellow method in my custom jQuery files and I set `jquery` in the dependency parameter when I enqueue my custom JS files.

```
(function($) {
   "use strict";
    // jQuery code goes here
})(jQuery); 
var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Please show us how exactly you have registered and enqueued your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem my own. I just deleted the last line-

```
var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

from my jQuery file then I get rid of the Uncaught TypeError.